# How to send UDP packets between an Android tablet and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, raspberry-pi

I need to establish wireless communication between an Android tablet and a Raspberry Pi. To do this, I have been writing an Android application that will serve as the client, and I have C code running on the Raspberry Pi for it to be the server. I have already configured the Pi as a wireless hotspot so that it has its own wireless network. I am using the Edimax EW-7811Un usb wireless adapter on the Pi.

I can successfully a message from the Android app to the Pi; however, the Pi is unable to echo the message back to the Android app.

Here is the C server code running on the Raspberry Pi:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t len;
   char mesg[1000];
   int returnv;

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(3490);
   bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   for (;;)
   {
      len = sizeof(cliaddr);
      n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
      mesg[n] = 0;
      printf("Received the following:\n");
      printf("%s",mesg);
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
      returnv = sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len);
      printf("Sent %d bytes.\n", returnv);
   }
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of the Android app code:

```
package com.example.thehelloworld;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String SERVERIP = "131.215.136.203";
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 3490;
    public String message;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message that the user entered. 
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Set the xml file to be activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.displaymessage);

        // and start thread to do networking
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
    }

public class Client implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // send message to Pi
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            String sentence = message;
            sendData = sentence.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            // get reply back from Pi
            byte[] receiveData1 = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData1, receiveData1.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            clientSocket.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also included the following permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The Android code gets stuck at the call to `clientSocket.receive(receivePacket)`. However, it seems like the server code finishes sending the message back, as the return value of the sendto call is equal to the number of bytes in the message.

It seems likely that there might be some sort of firewall issue on either the Android side of the Pi side. If this is the case, how might I configure firewall settings so that the right ports/IPs are available?

Any insight on how I can fix this issue so that UDP communication can go both ways would be very appreciated! Also, if there is a better way to send strings between the Android tablet and C code running on the Raspberry Pi, I would love to hear about it.

(Note: I also tried using TCP on both sides for communication, but the Android code would keep getting stuck at the line `Socket s = new Socket("131.215.136.240", 3490);` and I couldn't find out why. The code was not throwing any error, but it would get stuck at that line.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add to the code how you would extract the received message from `receivePacket`? If you think fire walls play a role then switch them off. Your server code should run on any pc too. Did you try?

Comment: Isn't there a return value for receive() ? What if 1024 is more then the message length? Would the receive call wait for 1024? Try with sendData.length instead of 1024.

Comment: I was extracting the received message by initializing a new string with String received = new String(receivePacket.getData());, however, I also had a log statement here and it is never reached. This is how I know the android tablet is not receiving. 

As for using sendData.length, that also didn't help but thanks for the suggestion! 

I am using the Hisense Sero 7 Lite - any idea on how to configure the firewall?

Also, I did try the server C code (running on Pi) along with client C code running on my Macbook and it all works fine.

Comment: What???? Can your android app communicate with your C server on mac and all is ok??? Does that Hisence Android have a firewall? Switch it off! Kill it! Ive never seen an Android device with a firewall..

Comment: I actually just got it to work! I had to connect my Android tablet to the wireless network of the Pi instead of a different network, but now it works fine. Thanks for the help!